# Write value to specific cell to Workbook with VBA code using VB.NET

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

I have code in Excel VBA that finds a specific value in column 2 and writes the value in that found rows column 3:

```vb
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Cells.Find("ProjectNumber", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, 3).Value = "TEST"
```

I am trying to get that function to run from my Visual Studio application.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Module Automate_Excel

Public xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
Public xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
Public xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
Sub Excel_FinishProject()

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("G:\100 Databases\Projects Schedule.xlsx")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1")

'Write
    xlWorksheet("Sheet1").Cells(Cells.Find("ProjectNumber", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, 3).Value = "TEST"

    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
End Sub

End Module
```

It is giving me errors like

> xlwhole is not declared

and

> cells is not declared

My understanding is it should be coming from the type library of Excel and code such as:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 5) = "TEST"
```

which does use "cells".

Comment: You need to fully qualify each enumeration. `Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole` in this case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xllookat - In an Excel/VBA environment, those are optional, so you never notice them.

Comment: Alright, now it returns the cells not being declared

Comment: Isn't it? I have two places that has "cells" in teh second one I have it "cells.find" don't I?
It returns 
"worksheet cannot be indexed because it ahs no default property"

Comment: VB.net does not know what `Cells` is without a qualifier. Again, in a VBA environment, you do not have to be this explicit, but in VB.NET you do, as there is no "default context"

Comment: I understand, both your edits return the same error for me that "worksheet cannot be indexed because it ahs no default property"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238637/discussion-between-eduards-and-brax).

Comment: Code I have so far is
````
xlWorkSheet.Cells(xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find("ProjectNumber", Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole).Row, 2) = "TEST"
````
which doesn't return error in error list but upon running it returns "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Type mismatch. (0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fully qualify each enumeration. In this case,

```
Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole
```

[XlLookAt enumeration (Excel)](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xllookat)

In an Excel/VBA environment, they are just a basic enumeration.

`Cells` in your code is also not fully qualified. `Cells.Find` needs a worksheet qualifier. VB.NET does not know what `Cells` is without a qualifier. Again, in a VBA environment, you do not have to be this explicit, but in VB.NET you do, as there is no "default context"

Your `xlWorkSheet` variable is not indexed. It's already holding a single reference to `xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` - So you don't specify the name of it again.

Also, you should store the result of the `Find` in a `Range` variable before using it instead of trying to do it all in one line. Then you can check to see if it "didn't find anything" before you try to use the result, and can even see what the result is before taking action

```
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim result as Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find("ProjectNumber", lookat:=Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole)
If result IsNot Nothing Then
    ' xlWorkSheet.Cells(result.Row, 3).Value = "TEST"

    ' OP says this works instead
    xlWorkSheet.Cells(result.Row, 3) = "TEST"

End IF
```

Comment: In my case I don't need ("Sheet1") in teh code as it returns an error and is declared previously in the code. However running the code says "System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Value' on type 'Range' not found.'" When in fact I do have a value in column 1 that I am looking for - the cell that says "ProjectNumber"

Comment: I was able to fix it.. I noticed you have ".value" like in VBA but I get that in VB.NET you just straight up write the value. I t seems to work now. Gonna run some more tests and comment about it. If that was the case then, please edit the answer and I will gladly accept it as teh correct one

EDIT: YES that was the case, so you need to remove ".value" and it works then. Thank you very much